# Is it possible to load a UMD module via script tag from a CDN and use it in a React component instead of importing it the usual way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, umd

I want to use [this package](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf) but it's extremely large and is adding a lot of bloat to my bundle. Due to some office restrictions I'm not able to set up lazy loading/chunking via webpack at the moment.

I found a CDN for the above lib:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@react-pdf/renderer@1.5.3/dist/

But I'm not sure how to use it. Like which of these many files should I load? All of them? and will the exports that I was able to access before be available as variables on the window object?

I never loaded something I needed in a React component via CDN like this. Here's what the code looked like when importing the usual way:

```
import { pdf, Document, Page, Image, Link } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

<Document title="hello" author="world">
  <Page style={styles.page}>
   // etc...
  </Page>
</Document>
```

How can I still use the lib if loading from CDN?

Comment: I don't see how importing it from the cdn can change your load time, or the final size of the modules you are going to import.

Comment: This component is in one of the inner pages which most users won't access. I will load this lib dynamically only when a user goes to this page. All other users won't need to download this lib and they won't since it's not added to the main bundle. @punjira

Comment: [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) might help

Comment: thanks! I may be able to solve the issue by generating the UMD module on my own and using it in combination with the `externals` flag. Lets see..